# Question which looks something similar to decimal expansion

Tags: real-numbers, decimal-expansion

Let $A=\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{5^i} : a_i=0,1,2,3 \text{ or } 4\}$. What is set $A$?

First thing I noticed is that the elements of set $A$ kind of resembles with how we write numbers of $[0,1]$ in decimal expansion as we know that each number in $[0,1]$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^i}$ where $a_i$ can be any of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0$ . So I think $A$ will also be $[0,1]$. I'm not really sure about my answer and if am I correct how can we rigoursly prove that $A=[0,1]$?

Comment: You are right about $[0, 1]$. This base-5 (called [quinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinary)) is entirely analogous to base-10 (denary, or decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Actually, if $x\in[0,1]$ and if you write $x$ in base $5$, then$$x=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots;$$besides, $1=0.444444444\ldots$

Note that if $x\in[0,1)$, you can define $a_1=\lfloor5x\rfloor$. Then, $a_2=\lfloor5^2x-5a_1\rfloor$, $a_3=\lfloor5^3x-5^2a_1-5a_2\rfloor$ and so on. Then$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{5^n}.$$